# Stop Ping.SendAsync by button click WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, ping

Good day. Help me please how can i stop SendPingAsync method here, i tried SendAsyncCancel but it stops only one thread, i need to cancel all pong threads.

```
private void refreshbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tokenSource != null) //check if its even initialized or not
            tokenSource.Cancel();

        lstNetworks.Items.Clear();
        string gate_ip = NetworkGateway();
        //Extracting and pinging all other ip's.
        string[] array = gate_ip.Split('.');
        for (int i = 1; i <= 255; i++)
        {
            string ping_var = array[0] + "." + array[1] + "." + array[2] + "." + i;

            //time in milliseconds           
            Ping(ping_var, 1, 4000);
        }
    }

    public void Ping(string host, int attempts, int timeout)
    {
        tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
                {
                    System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping ping = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
                    ping.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(PingCompletedCallback);
                    ping.SendAsync(host, timeout, host);
                }
                catch
                {
                    // Do nothing and let it try again until the attempts are exausted.
                    // Exceptions are thrown for normal ping failurs like address lookup
                    // failed.  For this reason we are supressing errors.
                }
        }, tokenSource.Token);
    }

    private void PingCompletedCallback(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // If an error occurred, display the exception to the user. 
        if (e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {

            string hostName = GetHostName(e.Reply.Address.ToString());
            string macAdress = GetMacAddress(e.Reply.Address.ToString());
            if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {

                Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                        lstNetworks.Items.Add(new InfoItem() { IP = e.Reply.Address.ToString(), MAC = macAdress, HOST = hostName });
                    lstNetworks.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("IP", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
                }));
            }
        }
        else {
            //Console.WriteLine(String.Concat("Non-active IP: ", e.Reply.Address.ToString()))
        }
    }
```

And every time i click refresh button i should start new ping operation. In my case is stops only one ping thread, but the rest keep working.

## UPDATE

I tried like you wrote, when i press refresh button again my app freezes until all threads will stop (30 sec). But when the app unfreeze the result is the same, all ping packets that i SendAsync before are added with new SensAsync packets that i sent second time. I need to stop not only the thread, but the SendAsync thread too. There is a method SendAsyncCancel, but how can i call it in the same time when cancelation token fires.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a different instance of the `TokenSource` each time. Instead, only create one, pass the same instance into all `Tasks`. Each `Task` will then check to see if the `Token` has a cancel request, then you can WaitAll on every one, and pass the `Token` into that.

```
private async void refreshbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tokenSource != null) //check if its even initialized or not
        tokenSource.Cancel();

    lstNetworks.Items.Clear();
    string gate_ip = NetworkGateway();
    //Extracting and pinging all other ip's.

    tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    string[] array = gate_ip.Split('.');

    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 255; i++)
    {
        string ping_var = array[0] + "." + array[1] + "." + array[2] + "." + i;

        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            if (tokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested) return;

            //time in milliseconds           
            Ping(ping_var, 1, 4000, tokenSource.Token);
        }, tokenSource.Token);
        tasks.Add(task);
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
}

public void Ping(string host, int attempts, int timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping ping = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();

        cancellationToken.Register(() => ping.SendAsyncCancel());

        ping.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(PingCompletedCallback);
        ping.SendAsync(host, timeout, host);
    }
    catch
    {
        // Do nothing and let it try again until the attempts are exausted.
        // Exceptions are thrown for normal ping failurs like address lookup
        // failed.  For this reason we are supressing errors.
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Added async/await so it does not block UI. Registered cancellation token for each Ping so that it can cancel itself.

Comment: I tried like you wrote, when i press refresh button again my app freezes until all threads will stop (30 sec). But when the app unfreeze the result is the same, all ping packets that i SendAsync before are added with new SensAsync packets that i sent second time. I need to stop not only the thread, but the SendAsync thread too. There is a method SendAsyncCancel, but how can i call it in the same time when cancelation token fires.?

Comment: See update. I added code so it does not block the UI thread, and add the usage of SendAsyncCancel

Comment: There is some problem. I added your code, but there is compilation Error on await Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray(), tokenSource.Token); - Cannot await void

Comment: See update. I forgot to change it from WaitAll to WhenAll